# Increase the number of spaces of a single tab indent in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I increase the number of spaces of a single tab indent?
I noticed that in another project a tab corresponds to four white spaces, but in the current one it is only two.
It is a simple question, but I have not found an answer and it would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Are you referring to Tabs? It's configurable in the code style settings: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Tabs and Indents | Tab size. Some projects may override it via EditorConfig. If you don't want it, disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Enable EditorConfig support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's configurable in the code style settings: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Tabs and Indents | Tab size.

Some projects may override it via EditorConfig. If you don't want it, disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Enable EditorConfig support.